# Undefined error in console while pulling JSON data

Tags: jquery, undefined

The JQuery Code:

```
function showData(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"retrieve.php",
            method:"GET",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data){
                // console.log(data);
                if(data){
                    x = data;
                }else {
                    x = "";
                }
                // console.log(x);
                for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                    console.log(x[i].name);
                }
            },
        });
    }
    showData();
```

But in console, I am getting: 1180 undefined. What can be the possible causes:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keS3a.png)

Live link [here](http://app.trafficopedia.com/crudjqajaxphp/)

I am ready to give any extra information if needed.

Additionally, This is retrieve.php→

```
    include 'dbConnection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $data = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}


// Returning JSON Format
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: *getting 1180 undefined* - no you're getting `undefined` repeated 1180 times

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Change `datatype: "json"` to `dataType: "json"`.  Simple typo.  Always worth checking what your `data` is actually being returned as.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the data back to json in javascript using JSON.parse(data). You need to do this as you are encoding json into a json-string in php using json_encode thus JSON.pare() is required at the javascript end to parse it back to object notation from json-string.

Comment: Isn't that what `datatype: "json"` does?  Edit: my bad, OP used `datatype` not `dataType`

Comment: Yo made my day. Typo error. Please write this in solution.

Comment: @matrixsapiens we don't generally provide "typo" as answer, it's one of the options when voting to close the question

Comment: Someone else may benefit from it in future.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting response from retrieve.php
And as you have specified datatype: "json" in request,
success function should automatically parse incoming json.

Now, try this:

```
success: function(data) {
  data.forEach(record => console.log(record.name));             
}
```